# Mysql how many search results

Tags: php, mysql

How can I check how many results is returned from mysql db?

Im using this code to fill a table with results from the mysql db:

```
   $qry_result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry_result))
```

Im want to display how many search results there was on the users search criteria...

Thanks

Comment: Hint: do accept responses, when these are satisfactory...A quick review of your 24 questions so far, show many with damn good responses, I think...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php).

```
$num_of_results = mysql_num_rows($qry_result);
```

It works for SELECT or SHOw. If the query is INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE use [`mysql_rows_affected`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php).